# Trying to loop between multiple dates to store them in textboxes

Tags: vb.net, ctype

I am trying to loop between multiple dates to store them in textboxes , i have the code but when it reaches to the second date according to this code

```
 CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), 
           TextBox).Text = dteTarget.ToShortDateString()
```

it shows error Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I know that the value is not null because when i replace

```
CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text
```

with `txtDate2= dteTarget.ToShortDateString` it gives me my value properly
   'First Date
        txtDate1.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString()

```
    Dim intCursor As Integer = 1

    'Keep adding days to the starting date until you've reached the end.
    Do Until MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.AddDays((intCursor)) >= MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date

        Dim dteTarget As Date = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.AddDays((intCursor))

        'Casts the Textbox using a naming convention: txtDate1, txtDate2, txtDate3, etc.
        CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text = dteTarget.ToShortDateString()

        intCursor += 1

    Loop

    'If the end date is not the same as the start date then add that.
    If MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date <> MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date Then

        CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionEnd.Date.ToShortDateString()

    End If
```

Comment: What the value of `intCursor`? Place a breakpoint and look what's in your `Me.Controls` collection.

Comment: please show the loop - there is not a lot of context there.  `txtDate2= dteTarget.ToShortDateString` wont compile if that is a control reference.  You might have control Names and control references confused.  `Button42` can have a name property of "SomethingDifferent"

Comment: i inserted full code

Comment: Your code is still not providing enough information. Your loop is creating a set of strings (e.g., "txtDate2", "txtDate3", "txtDate4", etc.) and most likely (-> we cannot be completely sure) one of these strings is not associated with the name of any control in your form. As suggested in the comments above, you should debug the code step by step to find the problem. On the other hand there is a solution which will avoid any error (although perhaps some right situations will be skipped anyway -> that's why you have to debug it through and properly understand the problem)...

Comment: `CType(Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString()), TextBox).Text = dteTarget.ToShortDateString()` is a very bad coding approach because you are assuming that the given object is Not Nothing, what might not be the case (actually this is what is provoking your error). You should replace this line with: `Dim item = Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString())
If (TypeOf item Is TextBox) Then
    CType(item, TextBox).Text = dteTarget.ToShortDateString()
End If`
This code checks whether it exists a TextBox with the given name.

Comment: PS: if you want someone in SO to know that you are talking to him/her you should include @ + the given nickname otherwise might not know it (i.e., Saragis & Plutonix didn't know about your comment unless they came back here after you wrote it). You get all our messages because you created this question.

Comment: @varocarbas thanks very much i will try the code you gave me

Comment: More than a code is an idea: before using an extension method make always sure that the given object is not null (Not Nothing). In this case, the error is most likely provoked by .Text (extension method) because all what is written before is null (Nothing). Also I insist: debug your code because it is clearly not behaving as you were expecting and some cases might be skipped.

Comment: @varocarbas i tested your code that you gave me it doesnt give an error but still item is nothing ! i dont know why i have created txdDate1 textbox until txtdate7 why it cant fiind them

Comment: As said, you should debug your code properly and think carefully about what you want it to do. If you got lost, just start over by doing everything calmly and step by step. Also in the future, bear in mind that we want to help but cannot be here fixing all the problems you come across, much less without the required information. I think that have already been helpful and understanding enough; and that you should continue fixing this by your own.

Comment: May be this throws an error? `Me.Controls("txtDate" & (intCursor + 1).ToString())`

Comment: @T.S. the problem seems to be that it cant find the textboxes that are  created in windows form . thats why he throws the error. if i replace that ctype code directly with txtDate2.text = something it works perfectly.